# Prove $x^n < y^n \implies x<y$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x,y>0$

Tags: real-analysis

$x^n < y^n \rightarrow x<y$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^+,n\in\mathbb{N}$.

It would be easy if the arrow would point to the left side...

Could someone give me a hint?

Attempt with a proof by contradiction:

Assume that $x^n < y^n$ and $x \geq y$, then $y^{-1} \geq x^{-1}$ and therefore $x=x^n\cdot x^{-n+1} < y^n\cdot y^{-n+1}=y$.

Which would be a contradiction to $x \geq y$.

Comment: I'm only glancing at this, but I think you'd definitely need to say something to justify the last strict inequality in your proof attempt. I could be missing something simple, but it's not obvious to me why $$x^n \cdot x^{-n+1} < y^n \cdot y^{-n+1}$$ would hold based on what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y+\cdots + y^{n-1})<0$

As $x^{n-1} + \cdots + y^{n-1}>0$, there must be $x-y<0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a proof by induction would be more traditional for this type of problem.

We know that $x^{1} < y^{1}$. Now, assume that $x^{n}< y^{n}$ for some $n$. We need no ony show that $x^{n+1}< y^{n+1}$.

But this is easy since we may multiply both sides of $x^{n}< y^{n}$ by x ad then use the fact that $x<y$.

$$ x^{n}<y^{n} \rightarrow x^{n}x<y^{n}x\rightarrow x^{n+1}<y^{n}x <y^{n}y = y^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that the function $f : x\mapsto x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is strictly increasing, since its derivative $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$$ is positive on $]0,+\infty[$.
$$x^n<y^n\Longrightarrow x=f(x^n)<f(y^n)=y$$